# changing filepath and creating directory in python

Tags: python, path

```
filepath = bpy.data.filepath
directory = os.path.dirname(filepath)
path = directory + "/" + "BakedTextures_" + obj + "/" + obj + "_" + map + "Tex.png"
```

Trying to define a path variable while creating a folder inside my blend file directory to later use that variable for saving a baked image texture made in Blender. So far with this code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\GOOGLE_DRIVE\WORK\3D_Work\OldWorld\Ducs_Armor\Ducs_Armor.blend\Text", line 15, in <module> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "type") to str Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong with my backslashes and probably something else, but I can't figure it out on my own, can you help please?

Comment: The string concatenation doesn't work because (at least) one of the variables isn't a string.

Answer (score 2):

Python has useful functions built-in to handle common pathname manipulations.

```
import os
desired_path = os.path.join(some_existing_path, "some_folder", "some_file_name.ext")
```

See [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), and see [shutils](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutils) for high-level file operations.

to test if a directory exists, and make it when not found):

```
if not os.path.exists(directory_to_test):
    os.makedirs(directory_to_test)
```